# Jquery appendto modal is removed after closing

Tags: jquery, html

I use this Jquery in order to display modal box.
I append it to other div, because otherwise i face problems with design / z-index.

```
       $j(this).closest('div.product').find('.productmodal').appendTo("#bodypro").modal('show');
```

This works fine however when closing the modal it does not place back but completely removes it.

Any ideas how to fix ? In other words how can I take care that it does not get removed or how do I can place it back manually ?

Comment: Can you show what is called when you close the modal?

Comment: This is automatic I guess by Bootstrap / Jquery.. When I look in console I see nothing ? How could I show it to you ?

Comment: Ok..Sorry but I'm not aware of any default jQuery function for modal.. (& haven't worked with biitstrap)

Comment: Check if this helps though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493280/close-bootstrap-modal

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: Please provide a link to  where its used or a fiddle if possible :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts !

Comment: Went through it.. I think the issue is that the modal's are being appended dynamically and on click of close they're attribute simply changes to hidden, but the element stays there.. You might wanna look at this: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-modals/ & maybe rework the way that modals are 'shown' in the first place :)