# bootstrap modal closes when ok on alert() is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap modal is closing when I click on "Ok" button showing from "alert()" function.

```
$("#expample").modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false,
    show: true
});
```

Below is my jquery:

```
$('.sendToUser').on('click', function (){
            var selectedLyrics = $('#selectedLyricsInput').val();
            if($("input[name='selectUserRadio']").is(":checked") == false){
                alert('Please, select a user to send.');
                return;
            }
        });
```

Although, hitting "Enter" or "Esc" on keyboard is working fine and also, clicking outside the modal; the modal is not closing which is fine.

Below is my html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="userSelectionModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="userSelectionModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-likes" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Select User</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div style="margin-bottom: 50px;" id="populateUsers">

                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="selectedLyricsInput" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success sendToUser" data-dismiss="modal">Send</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            {{--<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>--}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am creating an alert popup from an event on the modal but when clicked on the "ok" of the alert() popup, it disappears.

**How to prevent closing of the modal after clicking on "OK" on the alert popup?**

Thanks

Comment: Please add html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modal is closing, because you have `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute on the `.sendToUser` button. Removing this attribute should prevent the modal from closing.

Comment: Glad to help. You may want to close the modal manually in your method - [here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493280/close-bootstrap-modal) :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove attribute `data-dismiss="modal"` at the `.sendToUser` element. 
If you need to close modal, you just need to add the code:

```
$('#userSelectionModal').modal('hide')
```

Answer (score 0):

use within your script

```
window.location = "..\path after validation"
```

also avoid **data-dismiss="modal"** in submit button

Answer (score 0):

Simply instantiate a variable that's tied to the events firing within the modal window - to **false**, further set the variable to **false** when deemed necessary (e.g. to prevent closing the modal when the alert pops up), and then finally when the window should normally close, do a quick "if check" that assesses if the variable is finally **true** and if it is, fire off the functionality that lets the modal close. This ensures that the modal window will close only when you allow it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).