# Close Bootstrap Modal (using Javascript Not Jquery) when execute a function

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

i wanna close bootstrap modal when execute a function i did it but when open modal again i have to double click to open it i wanna open it again with one click not double, Thanks

my code to close bootstrap modal (js)

```
// To Close Modal
        document.getElementById('ItemModel').classList.remove('show');
        document.getElementById('ItemModel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0].remove();
        document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
        document.body.style.padding = '0';
```

Comment: Most likely because you are removing the modal instead of actually closing it.

Comment: i did not remove the modal i just removed "show" class to hide it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493280/close-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: yes but i wanna make it with javascript not jquery

Comment: i did it with javascript but the problem is when opening the modal again i have to double click to open it not once like before

Comment: Post the code of opening the modal too please. Or better yet: provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I believe we all know it's most likely a workaround. Sometimes this will get the job done more easy. Hence a workaround to show/hide Bootstrap 4 modals.

Without jQuery (but in TypeScript) you can use the following logic:

```
showModal(){
    let modal = document.getElementById('downloadModal') as HTMLElement;
    let modalDismiss = modal.querySelector('[data-dismiss]') as HTMLButtonElement;
    let backdrop = document.createElement('div') as HTMLElement;

    modal.setAttribute('aria-modal', 'true');
    modal.style.paddingRight = '16px';
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    modal.removeAttribute('aria-hidden');

    document.body.style.paddingRight = '16px';
    document.body.classList.add('modal-open');

    backdrop.classList.add('modal-backdrop', 'fade');
    document.body.appendChild(backdrop);

    backdrop.addEventListener('click', this.hideModal.bind(this));
    modalDismiss.addEventListener('click', this.hideModal.bind(this));

    setTimeout(function(){
        modal.classList.add('show');
        backdrop.classList.add('show');
    }, 200);
}

hideModal(){
    let modal = document.getElementById('downloadModal') as HTMLElement;
    let modalDismiss = modal.querySelector('[data-dismiss]') as HTMLButtonElement;
    let backdrop = document.querySelector('.modal-backdrop');

    modal.classList.remove('show');
    backdrop.removeEventListener('click', this.hideModal.bind(this));
    modalDismiss.removeEventListener('click', this.hideModal.bind(this));

    setTimeout(function(){
        modal.style.display = 'none';
        modal.removeAttribute('aria-modal');
        modal.removeAttribute('style');
        modal.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
        document.body.removeAttribute('style');
        document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
        backdrop.remove();
    }, 200);
}
```

I hope this doesn't stop you from converting it to vanilla JavaSript logic.