# Closing Blazor modal with multiple modals

Tags: html, modal-dialog, blazor

First of all, I've seen this [Close Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493280/close-bootstrap-modal) but of some reason it's not working for me.

I have a page, where one modal is called from like this

```
<button type="button" @onclick="@(()=>modal.Show<LandingPageHelpPopUp>())" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">Click here to get help</button>
```

That page's code look like this

```
<div class="modal-dialog" id="myModal" style="margin-left:-200px;margin-bottom:-550px;position:absolute;">
    <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:gray;">
        <div class="modal-body" style="color:black;">
            <p>Here you can observe the controlling of the curtains by others. If the queue is empty, and you'll like the control, hit this button.</p>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="float:right;border:none;margin-bottom:-25px;">
                <label class="custom-close" @onclick="@(()=>modal.Show<LandingPageHelpPopUp2>())">Next page</label>
                <button class="next-button" style="margin-left:-3px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<img src="css/arrow-help.png" class="arrow-help">
```

From here, I'd like to see another modal. To do that, I guess I have close the first one first, in order to not create a double layer of modals - if that makes sense. That's where I have used the linked thread in the beginning, but somehow it doesn't work.

The second modal's code look like this

```
<div class="modal-dialog" id="myModal2" style="margin-left:-200px;margin-bottom:-550px;position:absolute;">
    <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:gray;">
        <div class="modal-body" style="color:black;">
            <p>If other users is in the queue, click here to get in line.</p>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="float:right;border:none;margin-bottom:-25px;">
                <label @onclick="@(()=>modal.Show<LandingPageHelpPopUp>())">Previous page</label>
                <button class="next-button" style="margin-left:-3px;margin-top:-2px;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<img src="css/arrow-help2.png" class="arrow-help2">
```

In my index.html I've these two scripts, that is meant to toggle the modals. That is if one modals is open, when the other one is shown, it should close.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".custom-close").on('click', function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".custom-close2").on('click', function () {
            $('#myModal2').modal('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's some screenshots, showing that the previous modal does not get closed, so it's just creating multiple layers of modals on top of each other. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAQ8a.png), [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LMxK.png), [And here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0MbN.png)

Sorry for all the unnecessary code (styling, bad naming etc)

Doe any of you know why the previous modal is not getting closed, whenever the next is getting shown?

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but there are plenty of Blazor Modal dialog solutions on the internet - search "Blazor Modal Dialog" - that don't use javascript.  There's even one of mine.  The Bootstrap Modal Dialog is a classic example of something that needs re-writing for Blazor.

Comment: Using jquery etc will make it more complicated. Implementing modal in blazor is very straightfoward. In your case, use two bools (showDiag1, showDiag2). And render the modals on condition if(showDiag1) { <Diag1/> } if(showDiag2) { <Diag2/> }. Toggle these two boolean based on the triggers (button clicks etc).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to find a solution without javascript.

Comment: This solved my problem and made it much more simple: https://gist.github.com/conficient/ba98d1662c659e170ec16650acea05c8